Devexpress XtraGrid CustomDrawCell: Repaint of cell only on mouse over/ clicking on form elements
I have a annoying problem with repainting my devexpress XtraGrid.
I use this code to draw Icons into a cell:
Private Sub CtlGridView_CustomDrawCell(sender As Object, e As RowCellCustomDrawEventArgs) Handles CtlGridView.CustomDrawCell
        If e.Column.FieldName = NameOf(DataModel.Contract.Status) Then
            Dim view As GridView = CType(sender, GridView)
            Dim iconKeys As New List(Of String)

        ' Check Validation
        Dim guidString As String = view.GetRowCellValue(e.RowHandle, NameOf(DataModel.Contract.GuidId)).ToString()
        Dim guidId As Guid

        If Guid.TryParse(guidString, guidId) Then
            Dim validationResult As New DataModel.ValidationResult()

            ' Check if result is in cache
            If Not _validationCache.TryGetValue(guidId, validationResult) Then
                Task.Run(Sub()
                             Using taskContext As New DbContext()
                                 Dim entry As DataModel.Contract= taskContext.Contracts.Find(guidId)
                                 If entry IsNot Nothing Then
                                     validationResult = entry.Validate(taskContext, exitOnFirstError:=True)
                                 Else
                                     validationResult = New DataModel.ValidationResult
                                 End If

                                 ' Add result to cache
                                 _validationCache.TryAdd(guidId, validationResult)

                             End Using
                         End Sub)
            End If

            If cellValue = "O" Then
                iconKeys.Add("trackingchanges_showmarkup")

            ElseIf cellValue = "T" Then
                iconKeys.Add("trackingchanges_trackchanges")

            ElseIf cellValue = "I" Then
                iconKeys.Add("functionsinformation")

            ElseIf cellValue = "G" Then
                iconKeys.Add("trackingchanges_locktracking")

            ElseIf cellValue = "W" Then
                iconKeys.Add("trackingchanges_allmarkup")

            ElseIf cellValue = "K" Then
                iconKeys.Add("business_cash")
            End If

            If validationResult.Icon IsNot Nothing Then
                iconKeys.Add(validationResult.Icon)
            End If

            If iconKeys.Count > 0 Then
                Dim iconSize As New Size(32, 32)
                IconHelper.DrawIcons(e, iconKeys, _imageCollection, iconSize)
            End If

            e.Handled = True

        End If

    End If
End Sub

As you can see, I am using a task to perform a validation, and with the validation result, I get back the icon name, which I then use to draw into the cell. This works without any issues, but there is a problem: the icon is displayed only after moving over the cell with my mouse or clicking some buttons on the form. It is related to the repaint of the form, but I don't know how to handle it.
Here is a link to a video which shows the effect:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1EAXSd2S4wczKdtq2E4KFR47eEAtQRY3L/view?usp=drive_link
Unfortunately the little bird can't help me either :-)
It seems to work ok, but some validation icons appearing first after moving the mouse over it.
I tried to invalidate the entire view/row/cell like this:
            If Not _validationCache.TryGetValue(guidId, validationResult) Then
                Task.Run(Sub()
                             Using taskContext As New DbContext()
                                 Dim entry As DataModel.InstAuftrag = taskContext.InstAuftraege.Find(guidId)
                                 If entry IsNot Nothing Then
                                     validationResult = entry.Validate(taskContext, exitOnFirstError:=True)
                                 Else
                                     validationResult = New DataModel.ValidationResult
                                 End If

                                 ' Add result to cache
                                 _validationCache.TryAdd(guidId, validationResult)

                             End Using
                         End Sub)
                   view.invalidate
            End If

This works only for the initial load, but when I scroll down my list, the GUI is locked for some time, which is really annoying.
Is there any better way to accomplish this task?
Thank you!

Adding
                             view.RefreshRow(e.RowHandle)

here:
            Task.Run(Sub()
                         Using taskContext As New DbContext()
                             Dim entry As DataModel.Contract= taskContext.Contracts.Find(guidId)
                             If entry IsNot Nothing Then
                                 validationResult = entry.Validate(taskContext, exitOnFirstError:=True)
                             Else
                                 validationResult = New DataModel.ValidationResult
                             End If

                             ' Add result to cache
                             _validationCache.TryAdd(guidId, validationResult)
                             view.RefreshRow(e.RowHandle)
                         End Using
                     End Sub)


Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
